# Objective C - How to move a file from a location to another?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Beginner at Objective C here, I have this code:

```
//Path of management log file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *urlPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Logs/log.txt"];

NSURL *source = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlPath];

//Destination
NSURL * destination = [self.pathControl URL];

//Move file from source to that destination directory.
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:source toURL:destination error:nil];
```

The problem is that it doesn't do anything. It can compile, but nothing happens. Am I using copyItemAtURL method wrong?

Comment: What's the contents of pathControl?

Comment: Luke, use the force er error parameter! Really, provide the error parameter and add a return status variable and then log the error variable if the status is `NO`.

Comment: @Zaph , not it's just a naming convention, documentsDirectory is just a variable name. It is pointing to the path /User/admin/Library/Logs directory. I will have to change the name later on.

Comment: OK but If the naming is confusing and/or inconsistent that is a mistake.

Comment: @AndyIbanez , the contents of pathControl are a URL which is stored when user browses for a location to retrieve this log file. NSLog of the pathControl reveals that the URL address is indeed the correct place where user specifies.

Answer (score 1):

Use to error indicators to understand errors:

```
NSError *error;
BOOL status = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:source toURL:destination error:&error];
if (status == NO ) {
    NSLog(@"errorL %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Should be `if (!status)` rather than `if (status == NO)`.

Comment: @mipadi Docs: Returns NO if an error occurred. `!status` is just a preference and I like `status == NO` because it is harder to miss.

Comment: `if (!status)` evaluates to true if `status` is `NO`. (You generally don't compare directly to `YES` and `NO` in Objective-C, partly for stylistic/readability reasons and partly because of edge cases that can occur when comparing boolean values against `YES` and `NO` specifically.)

Comment: Yes and no. In this case the return value is a `BOOL` so a comparison to `NO` is reasonable and accurate. Comparing a non `BOOL` as a `BOOL` is unsafe, convert first.

Comment: Ok so I get this as an error: errorL Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "“logfile.txt” couldn’t be moved to “admin” because an item with the same name already exists." UserInfo=0x6080000f2d00 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/admin/Library/Logs/logfile.txt, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/admin/Documents, NSFilePath=/Users/admin/Library/Logs/logfile.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800045ac40 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of that method, is to copy a file and move it a specific location, in order for a file to be copied, it needs to exist beforehand, correct? I'm probably being dumb somewhere along the lines of literal sense, but anyone want to clarify for me what's wrong?

Comment: The source file must exist, the destination file must not already exist. That is the rule for copyItemAtURL. [copyItemAtURL  documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:) If a file already exists at the destination location remove it prior to copying a file to that location.